# Converting JsValue to String

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Reading through this [article](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson), I can't figure out how to convert my `Some(JsValue)` to a String.

Example:

```
val maybeString: Option[JsValue] = getSomeJsValue(); // returns Some(JsValue)

val str: String = maybeString match {
  case Some(x) => x.as[String]
  case _       => "0"
}
```

run-time error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationErr
or(validate.error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
```

Comment: If you're sure to have a JsString: maybeString.map(_.toString)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to compose multiple Options, that's what flatMap is for:

```
maybeString flatMap { json =>
  json.asOpt[String] map { str =>
    // do something with it
    str
  }
} getOrElse "0"
```

Or as a for comprehension:

```
(for {
  json <- maybeString
  str <- json.asOpt[String]
} yield str).getOrElse("0")
```

I'd also advise to work with the value inside the map and pass the Option around, so a None will be handled by your controller and mapped to a `BadRequest` for example.

Comment: OK - your first implementation was successful for me. I used `asOpt[Long]` instead since `asOpt[String]` didn't match, i.e. returned "0"

Comment: try to avoid using 'get' or 'getOrElse'

Answer (score 3):

Your error comes from the fact that you don't impose enough condition on x's type : `maybeString` is an `Option[JsValue]`, not `Option[JsString]`. In the case `maybeString` is not an `Option[JsString]`, the conversion fails and raises and exception.

You could do this :

```
val str: String = maybeString match {
  case Some(x:JsString) => x.as[String]
  case _       => "0"
}
```

Or you could use `asOpt[T]` instead of `as[T]`, which returns `Some(_.as[String])` if the conversion was successful, `None` otherwise.

Comment: Well, if I have `Option[JsValue]`, how can I convert that to a `String`?

Comment: @Kevin `maybeString.map(_.toString).getOrElse("defaultString")`, but that will transform all `Some[JsValue]` (ie give you "defaultString" only when `maybeString` is empty). I thought from your question you wanted to get the string representation if your `Option[JsValue]` happened to be a `Some[JsString]` and get a default value otherwise.

Comment: (too slow to edit previous comment) It will give you "defaultString" only when `maybeString` is `None` *

Comment: I believe that I understand you're helping me on how to convert a `Some(JsString)` to a `String`, but what if I have a `Some(JsValue)`? (Sorry if I'm repeating myself. I'm just not seeing how to go from Some(JsValue) to String...)

Comment: Doesn't `maybeString.map(_.toString).getOrElse("default")` work ? This   should take any `Option[JsValue]` and return its string representation, or "default" if the option is empty. What's the error message ?